# Xml Deserializer fails to deserialization

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, deserialization

I would like to deserialize the xml file to a object but unable to get the context attribute from the below xml to the object.

```
<Receipt>
    <Data context="LastYear">
      <OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity  ID="5011">
        <Amount>5000</Amount>
        <DatePaid>41274</DatePaid>
        <TaxDeducted>1000</TaxDeducted>
        <AllowableExpenses>2000</AllowableExpenses>
        <Status>Ok</Status>
      </OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity>
    </Data>
    <Data context="CurrentYear">
      <OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity  ID="5012">
        <Amount>5000</Amount>
        <DatePaid>41274</DatePaid>
        <TaxDeducted>1000</TaxDeducted>
        <AllowableExpenses>2000</AllowableExpenses>
        <Status>Ok</Status>
      </OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity>
    </Data>
</Receipt>
```

Class Object

```
public class Receipt
{
    public List<OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity> Data { get; set; }
}

public class OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity
{
    [XmlAttribute("openspaceID")]
    public int openspaceID { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int DatePaid { get; set; }
    public double TaxDeducted { get; set; }
    public double AllowableExpenses { get; set; }
    public DBEStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Code to generate deserialize

```
    Receipt otherIncomes = null;
    string path = "otherIncomes.xml";

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Receipt));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    otherIncomes = (Receipt)serializer.Deserialize(reader);         
    reader.Close();
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated !

Updated ( Object Structure)

```
public class Receipt
{
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlAttribute("context")]
    public int context { get; set; }

    public OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect the context to be stored?

Comment: updated revised object

Comment: I can store the context value to OtherIncomeReceiptDataEntity object but when serialize object back to XML I need to add that back to data element.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters but 'context' property is of int type while the attribute is not numeric (e.g. LastYear)

Comment: i have now changed the context to string but it did not work.